# Java; global class instance?

Tags: java, global-variables, global

As a means of developing my programming skills (I've taken one class so far), I've given myself a self assigned project. I am trying to build a playable game of chess.

Method: I wanted to design it so there would be a class for position (column and row), a class for type (int representation, int value, String name, Movement x) where movement is a reference from another class.

Then, there is a square class (position, type). Each square, for example, will be given a position and a type (for example empty, pawn, etc). I wanted to initialize each type outside of the square or 'play' class, as I want these to be predefined. So when I declare Square 1 = new Square(P1,EMPTY) I can initialize the square using a preset type and position. The issue is I would need to declare 'Empty' as a global type, which I'm not sure how to do. Does anyone see any way I can do this? Thanks a lot for the help. I'm using a version of oracle if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to recreate `null` (which means *no value*).

Comment: Make type an enum, and add EMPTY in the constants.

Comment: Then it might simplify things to model the board as `Type[][] board = new Type[8][8]` and forget about the square class.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with "type" as it doesn't make too much sense for a square to change type based on the chess piece associated with it. If you insist on it then so be it and use an `enum` as suggested in the comment.

```
public enum SquareType {
    KING, QUEEN, ... , EMPTY
}
```

If I didn't want to do that, and I don't, I would do one of two things:

1. Ditch the `position` of the pieces and replace it with a `Square` since that is also the location.
2. Add a reference to the chess piece in the `Square`; if the reference is `null` you know it's empty.

Because a piece cannot be at a position on the board without also being on a square, you reduce redundancies this way and there's no need for a "global" identifier.

When allocating the game board, which I would make a 2D array (also suggested) I would do:

```
// For a non-empty square
board[row][col] = new Square(new ChessPiece(...), ...);
// For an empty square
board[row][col] = new Square(null, ...);
```